# Is it possible to undefine a Java class using JRuby?

Tags: unit-testing, jruby

I have some ruby code that depends on a java library, but I want the ruby code to fail gracefully if a particular java class isn't available.

So I would like one of my unit tests to simulate that situation in order to assert "graceful failure".  But I only want it removed for the duration of that test, as other tests will depend on it.

So is it possible to undefine say, org.foo.SomeRandomJavaClass using JRuby?

Comment: I don't think so. AFAIK the Java compiler has access to any class as long as it has the fully qualified name of a package and a class (eg: `org.foo.SomeRandomJavaClass`)

Answer (score 0):

You could look into creating a custom [`ClassLoader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) and overriding the appropriate methods to throw a `ClassNotFoundException` if `org.foo.SomeRandomJavaClass` is being loaded. Specifically, take a look at overriding all the `find..` and `load...` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Class names- Java or otherwise are constants in JRuby. `Kernel.remove_const` and `Object.remove_const` are both private methods. There's probably a better way of achieving what you want than undefining classes...